# force:mdapi:deploy fails with RunLocalTests + test coverage > 75%

Tags: salesforcedx, code-coverage, mdapideploy

As other people (see [Code Coverage during sfdx force:mdapi:deploy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257922)) I am unable to move code using sfdx force:mdapi:deploy to another org due to Apex Class Coverage.

But as @sfdcfox notes out:

> If you specify RunLocalTests, the aggregate code coverage must be 75%

As you can see in the output I am way over this as nearly every class is way over 75%.

[image]

Comment: What does the coverage show in the deployment Status ? And also what does it show when you runall tests in the org?

Comment: Don't get your question. The screenshot shows the deployment status.

Comment: Well not from the deployment Status in the org ? Usually deployment sttaus setting in orgs show more info

Comment: Can your confirm that the metadata is deployed when there is a coverage problem at all? And where can I find this deployment status in the target org?